# Link between node->building->street in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, xml

**Data:** Raw OSM data (.osm XML file).

**Target:** Connect between house number represented by `node`, to street name represented by `way`.

**What I did:**

In [www.openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org) I can explore elements. So I point the `node` representing house number:

[image]

Then I searched by it's `osm_id` and found:

```
<node id="MY_NODE_ID" visible="true" version="1" changeset="..." timestamp="..." user="..." uid="..." lat="..." lon="...">
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="MY_HOUSE_NUMBER"/>
</node>
```

Then I searched this `node` and as expected I found it part of the building represented as `way`:

```
<way id="MY_BUILDING_ID" visible="true" version="1" changeset="..." timestamp="..." user="..." uid="...">
    <nd ref="MY_NODE_ID"/>
    <nd ref="..."/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
</way>
```

Finally I expect `MY_BUILDING_ID` to be part of another `way` representing the street. *But `MY_BUILDING_ID` appears only once in the XML file*. So I found street's `osm_id` and found it in the XML as:

```
 <way id="MY_STREET_ID" visible="true" version="10" changeset="..." timestamp="..." user="..." uid="...">
  <nd ref="..."/>
  <nd ref="..."/>
  <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  <tag k="name:en" v="MY_STREET_NAME"/>
  <tag k="source" v="user via ..."/>
 </way>
```

*But none of the `<nd ref="..."/>` isn't `MY_BUILDING_ID`*, and more over none of the `<nd ref="..."/>` appears again in the XML file.

**Conclusion:** How to link between known `MY_NODE_ID` to `MY_STREET_ID` so later it's easy to make the link between `MY_HOUSE_NUMBER` and `MY_STREET_NAME`?

Comment: I guess that you should edit OSM data and create an associated street relation for your house http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:associatedStreet. But most addressed are without such relation and if the address is without address:street tag you just can't link the address with the street in a reliable way. Finding the closest street gives often a correct result.

Comment: How to find the closest street? Just but shortest distance? Generally it's not always true...

Comment: That's what I meant. Shortest distance gives often a correct result, quite often not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task to connect the house number automatically to the street name will surely fail in many cases. Just imagine a street crossing with four different named streets, where the house number could be related to any of them.

The only working way is to add the full adress information to the house number during editig, using the [Karlsruher Schema](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/House_numbers/Karlsruhe_Schema).

The information might be added to a `node` representing the building entrance or the center of the building, or added to the closed `way` or `multipolygon relation` representing the building itself. Both methods are accepted, but it is up to the individual mapper to decide how he does it (or not).

Relations of type `associated street` are another method to combine a street with the house numbers.

You have to keep in mind that a street (of the same name) can be represented by several ways, either direction-wise or one after the other. You have to add all those to the relation.

And, the house number node does not have to be part of the building way.

Comment: Thanks, Basically what I wanted to do is implement simple geocoder by myself. Because I noticed that in Nominatim when I search for that street number I get the result, I assumed that this data encoded in the raw data. So how do they achieve this if ain't the data in the raw files?

Comment: Have you looked out for associated street relations?

Comment: MY_STREET_ID and MY_BUILDING_ID appears only once - ain't street relation associated with them and neither with the base node containing the tag of the house number: MY_NODE_ID appears only in the building `way`. So sure they manipulate it via "most closed" street etc?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the node you are talking about? Or the actual node ID? Usually the building/feature outline or the address node should contain either an *addr:street* tag or be part of an *associated street* relation. If none of those applies then there is an error in OSM.

Comment: @scai one example (I actually spotted this for many nodes): https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1712600303

Comment: @michael Yep, that's wrong, i.e. incomplete data. At least the house number and street name should be present, otherwise the data is ambiguous. You can only guess the corresponding street, which Nominatim probably also does. This can and it will fail for some addresses.

Comment: @scai guess=the most nearest etc logic? also - is this what probably nominatim geocoder algorithm doing?

Comment: Yes, see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview#Building_indexing